# Why didn't Yokodera send Azuki Azusa back to Okinawa?

Tags: hentai-ouji-to-warawanai-neko

Azuki Azusa is brought to the Tsutsukakushi residence from Okinawa after Yokodera accidentally makes a wish to the large cat statue in the storeroom. A little bit later, he learns that with this statue wishes can be taken back.

Is there any reason why he didn't take back his wish and send Azuki Azusa back to Okinawa?

[image]

Comment: I suspect there is no particular reason here. It is just used as a plot device for the love comedy between Yokodera, Azusa and Tsutsukakushi.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because she would throw a tantrum if he tried. She's been wanting him to show up in okinawa anyway.